# In WordPress, how do I offer a different image source for small screens?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

**In `WordPress`, how do I offer a different image source for smaller screens?**

The logo is set via the customizer in the `WordPress` dashboard. Now I'm looking for a good way to provide the smaller logo.

The theme I'm using is one I created.

**Methods I can think of:**

- use Media Queries with `CSS` `background`/`content`
- exchange the image source via `JavaScript`
- define the exchange somewhere in `WordPress` `functions.php`

If I use any of these methods, the user gets no influence on the logo exchange. Also, where would I pull the smaller logo from? I know `WordPress` stores uploads as `../uploads/year/month/file.jpg`.

I think in my specific case, it is unlikely that the user wants to exchange the logo. So it could be handled in the background.

But what if they delete or rename it by accident?

So this is what I'm stuck on.

**Methods could be implemented via `HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP` or `Plugin`. Suggestions are very much appreciated!**

Comment: You can try this method: https://blog.imagekit.io/how-to-deliver-responsive-images-to-browsers-across-multiple-devices-30cfae17390e

Comment: You can use only html with tag picture. See on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)

Comment: Thank you both, I think I found a decent solution! :) I have an if-statement set up now that checks if a logo was defined via WordPress. If not, it uses the images defined in a picture element, which responds to the change in screen width.